# What is the best way to get a game on the Battlefront 2015 DLC on PC?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2015

I would really like to play the dlc maps on Star Wars Battlefront 2015.  Unfortunately I can't find any games.  Does anyone know what is the best matchmaking region to play on?  Is death star, bespin, outer rim, or scarif easier to find?  I just want to try the DLC.  So if anyone could tell me what region and mode I can try?

Thanks.

Comment: I doubt a lot of people are still playing the first next-gen Battlefront game, when the second one has a much larger playerbase and all proposed-DLC released. You might just be out of luck due to the planned obsolescence of the first game.

Comment: It's true that that's possible, but it is still easy to play regular Cargo.  Walker assault occasionally, and heroes vs villains on the European servers.  What dice really should do, is add the dlc maps to the regular mode playlist, and make one new mode playlist which plays the dlcs special game modes.  Still, if anyone knows how to get a game...

Comment: curious, what do you mean by all proposed DLC release?  I thought that Battlefront 2 had it's last big update.

Comment: I meant that all DLC that had been planned has been released.